# Multiple reactive select input in a datatable

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm trying to create an interaction between the different filters in my data table. I can operate each filter independently but not together.
I looked on different topics and tried different methods but obviously there must be another problem.

That's the solution I picked.

```
filter1 <- reactive({
    fdt() %>% dplyr::filter(FinalData()$sous.themes %in% input$f_st)
  })

  filter2 <- reactive({
    fdt() %>% dplyr::filter(FinalData()$donnees %in% input$f_don)
  })

  filter3 <- reactive({
    fdt() %>% dplyr::filter(FinalData()$donnees %in% input$f_don) & dplyr::filter(FinalData()$sous.themes %in% input$f_st)
  })

  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "f_st", choices = filter2()$sous.themes)
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "f_don", choices = filter1()$donnees)
  })

  filter_final <- reactive({
    if (input$f_st != "Tous"){
    filter1()
    } else if (input$f_don != "Tous"){
    filter2()
    } else if (input$f_st != "Tous" & input$f_don != "Tous"){
    filter3()
    } else fdt()
  })

  #Rendu de la table d'extraction
  output$Synthese <-  DT::renderDT(DT::datatable({

    #Affiche le tableau
    filter_final()

  },
```

And here is the entire code.

```
library(DT)
library(readODS)
library(dplyr)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shiny)

#Lecture du fichier
base <- read_ods("base.ods")

#Fonction pour l'affichage des fiches de données
createLink <- function(val) {
  sprintf('<a href= "%s" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Fiches données</a>',val)
}

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title ="MobiDiag"),

  #Mise de en forme de la Sidebar
  dashboardSidebar(

    #Couleurs de l'entête
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.logo {
                                background-color: #8eb06a !important;
                                }
                                .navbar {
                                background-color: #a7cd7f !important;
                                }
                                '
    ))),

    #Texte principal
    h4(strong("Critères de sélection"), align="center"),

    #Liste des critères de sélection
    prettyCheckboxGroup("territoire", "Territoire",
                        thick = TRUE,
                        shape = "curve",
                        animation = "pulse",
                        choices = c("Communes centrales" = "Communes.centrales", "Communes pôles urbain" = "Communes.poles.urbain", "Communes secondaires" = "Communes.secondaires", "Communes rurales" = "Communes.rurales", "Ensemble territoire" = "Ensemble.territoire", "Périmètre élargit" = "Perimetre.elargit")),
    prettyCheckboxGroup("doc", "Documents de planification existants",
                        thick = TRUE,
                        shape = "curve",
                        animation = "pulse",
                        choices = c("Volet mobilité SCOT" = "Volet.mobilite.SCOT", "PDU obligatoire" = "PDU.obligatoire", "PGD volontaire" = "PGD.volontaire", "PLUI","Plan de mobilité rurale" = "Plan.mobilite.rurale", "PCAET", "PLUIHD")),

    #Et le miracle fut !
    actionButton("submit", ("Extraction")),

    br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),

    tags$img(src='logo_dreal.jpg', width = 40, height = 60),
    tags$img(src='inddigo.jpg', width = 40, height = 60)
  ),

  #Mise en forme de la page principale
  dashboardBody(
    fluidPage(

      shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
      tags$style(".btn.disabled {
                                background-color: red;
                                }"),

      #Onglets Extraction et Ajout de données
      mainPanel(width = 12,
                tabsetPanel(

                  #Onglet Extraction
                  tabPanel("Extraction",
                           fluidRow(
                             br(),
                             #Liste des différents filtres possibles sur le résultat
                             column(width=2,
                                    selectInput("f_st",
                                                "Sous-thèmes :",
                                                "")
                             ),
                             column(width=2,
                                    selectInput("f_don",
                                                "Données :",
                                                "")
                             ),
                             column(width=2,
                                    selectInput("f_check",
                                                "Validation :",
                                                "")
                             ),
                             column(width=2,
                                    selectInput("f_doc",
                                                "Documents de planification :",
                                                "")
                             ),
                             column(width=12, DT::dataTableOutput("Synthese"))

                           )
                  )
                )
      ))))

server = function(input, output, session) {


  shinyInput <- function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
    inputs <- character(len)
    for (i in seq_len(len)) {
      inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), ...))
    }
    inputs
  }

  #Création des colonnes bouton
  df <- reactiveValues(data = data.frame(
    validation = shinyInput(actionButton, 1,
                            id = "button_",
                            label = "Check",
                            style = "color: white; background-color: #222D32",
                            onclick = 'Shiny.onInputChange(\"select_button\",  this.id)'),
    lien_fiches = createLink(base$fiches.donnees)[1]
  ))

  #Création de la règle de filtre a partir des critères
  create_rules <- reactive({
    paste(c(input$territoire, input$doc), "== 'Oui'",  collapse = " | ")
  })

  #MExtraction des critères de la base
  FinalData <- eventReactive(input$submit,{
    if(is.null(c(input$territoire, input$doc)))
      return()
    else (base %>% filter_(create_rules()))
  })

  #MAssemblage des deux dataframe
  fdt <- eventReactive(input$submit,{
    tmp_fdt <- cbind(FinalData()[1:2], df$data)
    colnames(tmp_fdt) <- c("Sous-thèmes", "Données", "Validation", "Fiches données")
    tmp_fdt
  })

  filter1 <- reactive({
    fdt() %>% dplyr::filter(FinalData()$sous.themes %in% input$f_st)
  })

  filter2 <- reactive({
    fdt() %>% dplyr::filter(FinalData()$donnees %in% input$f_don)
  })

  filter3 <- reactive({
    fdt() %>% dplyr::filter(FinalData()$donnees %in% input$f_don) & dplyr::filter(FinalData()$sous.themes %in% input$f_st)
  })

  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "f_st", choices = filter2()$sous.themes)
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "f_don", choices = filter1()$donnees)
  })

  filter_final <- reactive({
    if (input$f_st != "Tous"){
    filter1()
    } else if (input$f_don != "Tous"){
    filter2()
    } else if (input$f_st != "Tous" & input$f_don != "Tous"){
    filter3()
    } else fdt()
  })

  #Rendu de la table d'extraction
  output$Synthese <-  DT::renderDT(DT::datatable({

    #Affiche le tableau
    filter_final()

  },

  #Argument sans quoi beaucoup de choses ne marchent pas !!!!
  escape = FALSE,
  selection = "none",

  extensions="Buttons",
  options = list(
    pageLength = 10,

    #Couleur du header de l'extraction
    initComplete = JS(
      "function(settings, json) {",
      "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#1A242F', 'color': '#fff'});",
      "}"),

    #Paramètrage des boutons d'export
    dom="Bfrtip",
    buttons =  list(list(
      extend = "collection",
      filename = "Extraction",
      buttons = c("copy", "csv", "excel", "pdf"),
      text = "Télécharger la sélection")
    ),
    language = list(paginate = 
                      list('next'="suivant", 
                           'previous'="précédent"),
                    info = "Pages de _PAGE_ à _PAGES_",
                    search = "Rechercher",
                    infoFiltered = "(filtre des _MAX_ lignes)")
  )
  ))

  #Mise à jour des filtres du tableau
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "f_st", choices = c("Tous", FinalData()$sous.themes))
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "f_don", choices = c("Tous", FinalData()$donnees))
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "f_doc", choices = c("Tous", input$doc))
  })

  #Evenement lié au click bouton
  observeEvent(input$select_button, {
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "f_check", choices = c("Tous", "Oui"))
    updateActionButton(session, inputId = "button_", label = "Oui")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

How about getting it in the same filter?

```
filter <- reactive({
    filtered_data <- fdt()
    if (input$f_st != "Tous"){
    filtered_data <- filtered_data %>% dplyr::filter(FinalData()$sous.themes %in% input$f_st)
    }
    if (input$f_st != "Tous"){
    filtered_data <- filtered_data %>% dplyr::filter(FinalData()$donnees %in% input$f_don)
    }
    if (input$f_st != "Tous"){
    filtered_data <- filtered_data %>% dplyr::filter(FinalData()$donnees %in% input$f_don) & dplyr::filter(FinalData()$sous.themes %in% input$f_st)
    }
   return(filtered_data)
  })
```

You might need to change some other elements of your code, but basically you need to be applying the filters to the same dataset iteratively, rather than applying to the original dataset each time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ! I tried your code but it did not work (some problem with length) so I adapted it

```
filter <- reactive({
filtered_data <- fdt()
if (input$f_st != "Tous"){
  filtered_data <- filtered_data[FinalData()$sous.themes %in% input$f_st,]
}
if (input$f_don != "Tous"){
  filtered_data <- filtered_data[FinalData()$donnees %in% input$f_don,]
}
if (input$f_st != "Tous" & input$f_don != "Tous"){
  filtered_data <- filtered_data[FinalData()$sous.themes %in% input$f_st & FinalData()$donnees %in% input$f_don,]
}
return(filtered_data)
})
```

It works with some of my data but in certain case it fail.

I have two types of errors:
When I have an apostrophe, it returns "no data".
In other cases it returns "NA"

Comment: I find the solution !